# How to upload the files on Azure App Service over FTPS using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to upload files from my local system to Azure app service over FTPS.

I am able to achieve this using Filezilla.

Now, I want to automate this process using Powershell.

Configuration of my app service looks like :

- **URL**       ftps://waws-prod-dm1-017.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot
- **Scope**        App Credentials
- **Username**     appname$appname
- **Password**     aq8----------------ddddF-------rssssg--------------z

More Information :
I want to download the App Service artifact on my local system
[image]
whatever artifact get downloaded on my local system,

[image]
I want to upload the same back to the app-service if required.

I have used the PowerShell from [here](https://gist.github.com/pbrumblay/6551936)

I am unable to do the same.

Can you please guide me regarding PowerShell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload/Publish WebApp Files to Azure via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787686/upload-publish-webapp-files-to-azure-via-powershell)

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Thanks for the response. But, It doesn't solve my issue. I just want a PowerShell where I can give fixed values like URL, username, password etc.. I need to add this powerhell script in some automation task.

Comment: hey @Eddie finally did you succeed in automating this task ? we have the same problem, did try many options but all have failed. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution for Powershell i think it will work for Azure Web app as well.

[Upload file to SFTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732025/upload-file-to-sftp-using-powershell)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesn't work for Azure App service